# Restart service Supervisor

Tags: supervisord

Is there any way to restart supervisor from the inside out?

I'm running a script through supervisor, to update html's and videos on a raspberry pi. But at some point I have to switch between 2 processes running on supervisor. So I rename the configs of the process that has to end to ".conf.disabled" and on the on that has to start I do the opposite.

That works fine, after that I can do a `sudo service supervisor restart` and that's when things go south.

Approx. 1 out of 2 times it just fails. Without any reason, if I try it a few seconds later it works. I put the same command twice in a script that runs when the configs have to switch, but no luck. It just fails twice in a row. Is there any solution to this?

Not sure as to whether it needs to be here or on another board. I'll be happy to move it if necessary.

Comment: `supervisorctl reread & supervisorctl reload` I would do that way as I am not 100% if the restart actually forces a re-read.

Comment: I did came across it that I had to do reread too, but didn't know of reload. Will try, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
supervisorctl reload
```

This worked for me.